# CSS slideshow issues with last image not showing up but for a split second

Tags: html, css, slideshow, css-animations

I have created a slideshow with much input derived from other very talented individuals (I'm learning).  However, my code seems to go all of the way to the fifth image, but quickly shifts right back to the first instead of staying on the same schedule as the previous four slides.  I am trying to avoid the use of JS or jQuery.  I feel it is easier to read, especially for me considering I have very little Java background.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web);
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  20% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  25% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  45% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  50% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  75% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  95% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -400%;
  }
}
body,
figure {
  margin: 0;
  background: #101010;
  font-family: Istok Web, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div#captioned-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 500%;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 60s slidy infinite;
}
figure.slider figure {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}
figure.slider figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: .6rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/1">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/2">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/3">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/4">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/5">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/6">
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

So I figure there has to be something wrong with the keyframes part.  However, I think I may just be horrible at that and am having a lot of trouble finding a good reference that makes sense to me.  I've messed with the percentages, but can't seem to get it right.  I mainly need to know how keyframes work and how the job is divided up amongst each slide.  I would even like to know how to add another slide into the mix, but tackling this first issue would be a great start. I appreciate you taking the time to dissect this.  All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I get to the reason why the last image shows up only for a split second, there are a few other changes that need to be made in-order for the slideshow to work properly:

- The CSS posted in question seems to have been coded with the assumption that there would be only 5 images but the HTML markup has six `.slider figure` elements. I am not sure if this was intentional or it is a mistake but I will explain the changes based on the HTML provided.
- First, the width of `figure.slider` should be changed to `600%` from `500%` because there are six images and each have to be `100%` width (that is, cover the entire body). This should always be calculated as (no. of elements * 100%). If this is not done, some of the images would wrap to the next line and will get hidden due to the `overflow: hidden` setting on the parent.
- Next, the width of `figure.slider figure` should be changed from `20%` to `16.67%` because we have six images now and so each image should have 1/6<sup>th</sup> of 100% as its width.
- When we have 5 images, at `left: 0%`, the first image would be shown, at `left: -100%`, the 2<sup>nd</sup> image would be shown and so only at `left: -400%` the 5th image would be shown. As per code provided in question, the `left: -300%` to `left: -400%` movement happens only between `95%` to `100%` and so the 5th image comes fully into view only at `100%` which is the same time as the end of the animation and **this is why the last image is displayed only for a split second**.
- In-order to address the aforementioned issue, the `keyframe` rules should be changed. Since for our case we have taken 6 images, we need 5 (n-1) slide movements and each slide movement is done over `5%` of the animation's duration. This means that a total of `25%` of the duration is used up by the slide movements. Now the remaining `75%` should be split up equally among the image elements so that each of them would be visible for x seconds before disappearing. So, we arrive at `12.5%` stay time for each image and `5%` slide movement time. Once we do this modification to `@keyframes`, we can see that each image gets their screen time (which is 12.5% of 60s = 7.5s).

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Istok+Web);
@keyframes slidy {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  12.5% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  17.5% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  30% {
    left: -100%;
  }
  35% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  47.5% {
    left: -200%;
  }
  52.5% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  65% {
    left: -300%;
  }
  70% {
    left: -400%;
  }
  82.5% {
    left: -400%;
  }  
  87.5% {
    left: -500%;
  }
  100% {
    left: -500%;
  }  
}
body,
figure {
  margin: 0;
  background: #101010;
  font-family: Istok Web, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
}
div#captioned-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 600%;
  font-size: 0;
  animation: 60s slidy infinite;
}
figure.slider figure {
  width: 16.66%;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: inherit;
}
figure.slider img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
}
figure.slider figure figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: .6rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="captioned-gallery">
  <figure class="slider">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/1">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/2">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/3">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/4">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/5">
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600/nature/6">
    </figure>
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Harry!  Dude!  You rock!  Best explanation by far!  I have been trying to figure this stuff out and you made it sound so much simpler.  Thank you so much.  I tried out the code and it works like a charm.  Now, if I need to edit anything within the @keyframes, I know how to do it.  I really appreciate the help.

Comment: Excellent answer, your point 5 makes clear the calcs for the keyframe movement. +1